# How to show total number of lines changed in git log one-line format?

Tags: git, awk, sed, command-line

I want to add the total number of lines changed for each commit in this output:

`git log --pretty=format:"%cd | %cn | %h | %s"`

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to modify this, but it's pretty straightforward:

```
function gcount() {
    git diff --shortstat $1 | sed -E 's/[^[:digit:][:space:]]//g' | awk '{ print $2+$3 }'
}

git log --pretty=format:"%h" | while read hash
do
    echo "$(gcount $hash)"
done | head > a.txt

git log --pretty=format:"%cd | %cn | %h | %s" | head > b.txt

paste b.txt a.txt
```